# What is the Pokemon move/attack that always leaves opponents with at least 1 hit point?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-third-generation

I remember that there was a move or attack one of my Pokemon had that caused damage to the opponent but would leave at least one hit point.

I am most interested about its avaibility in Leaf Green.

What is this move/attack, what Pokémon can learn it, and how?

Comment: Note that in Gen 4 and 5, they made this a TM.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**False Swipe** leaves an opponent with at least one health. In Leaf Green, the following Pokemon learn it by levelling up. Entries in bold are Pokemon which can be caught in Leaf Green; others can be acquired by trading:

- **Cubone (level 33)** (Sevault Canyon, Pokémon Tower floors 3-7)
- **Farfetch'd (level 46)** (Trade a Spearow to a girl in Vermillion City)
- Grovyle (level 53)
- **Marowak (level 39)** (Sevault Canyon, Victory Road floors 1-3)
- Nincada (level 25)
- Sceptile (level 59)
- Scizor (level 16)
- Scyther (level 16)
- Zangoose (level 55)

The following Pokemon can hatch with it as an egg, if their father had the move:

- Heracross
- Mawile
- Paras
- Pinsir
- Seedot
- Shroomish
- Spearow

Comment: Assuming you can get it in Third Generation, Smeargle can also learn False Swipe through its use of 'Sketch'

Answer (score 7):

False swipe

> False Swipe inflicts damage and if False Swipe deals more damage than the target's current HP, the target will always be left with 1 HP remaining. If the target has 1 HP remaining, False Swipe will hit and leave the target at 1 HP. This move is most often used to catch wild Pokémon.
>   If used against a substitute, False Swipe is able to break it, and will not leave the decoy with 1 HP.

Answer (score 7):

I think the move you mean is [False Swipe](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/False_Swipe_%28move%29):

> False Swipe inflicts damage and if False Swipe deals more damage than the target's current HP, the target will always be left with 1 HP remaining. If the target has 1 HP remaining, False Swipe will hit and leave the target at 1 HP. This move is most often used to catch wild Pokémon.
>   If used against a substitute, False Swipe is able to break it, and will not leave the decoy with 1 HP.

Following Pokemon learn this by leveling up in Generation 3 games:
*first number indicates the pokemons position in the national pokedex*

> 083 Farfetch'd on Level 46
>   104 Cubone on Level 33
>   105 Marowak on Level 39
>   123 Scyther on Level 16
>   212 Scizor on Level 16
>   253 Grovyle on Level 53
>   254 Sceptile on Level 59
>   290 Nincada on Level 25
>   335 Zangoose on Level 55

Additionally those Pokemon can learn False Swipe by [breeding](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_breeding):

> 021 Spearow when breeded with a Farfetch'd
>   046     Paras   when breeded with a Scyther or Scizor
>   127     Pinsir breeded with Scyther, Scizor or Nincada
>   214     Heracross breeded with Scyther, Scizor or Nincada
>   273     Seedot breeded with Farfetch'd or Zangoose
>   285     Shroomish breeded with Paras, Seedot or Mawile
>   303     Mawile breeded with Farfetch'd or Zangoose

Comment: OP is asking about Gen 3...some of the numbers are a bit different.

Comment: @Shinrai: Thanks for pointing this out. Has been too long I've gone through the series :D edited accordingly.